# Virtual Machines Type 1 Vs Type 2

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, operating-systems, process-hacker

I recently downloaded **Oracle Type 2 VM Hypervisor**, and I know there's a Type 1 Hypervisor too in the market.
I at least experienced that Type 2 is somewhat slow on my PC.
Actually I want to use VM for learning other OS and for Hacking. But I'm confused that which Type of Hypervisor will
**1. Keep more Privacy

2. Will be more Faster

3. Will be good for Learning other OS and Ethical Hacking**
My Laptop config. is Win 10 - 512GB SSD - 16GB RAM

Comment: It doesn't matter. How slow is "somewhat slow"? What exactly is slow? What are your computer's specs? Have you enabled hardware acceleration and graphics acceleration? Are guest tools installed?

Comment: Yep, I installed guest tools, but though I gave half of the CPUs to the VM, but as a common problem today, Ubuntu on VM is like 5 times slower than my host Windows 10 OS

Comment: Are computational loads slower too or just UI? What are your computer's specs? Have you enabled hardware acceleration and graphics acceleration? How much RAM is assigned to the VM?

Comment: **So what exactly is your question?** In order to use a type 1 Hypervisor you would lose your Windows installation, and be left with a shell of an operating system (ESXi for example) that would be running a VM on it.  If this is your only machine you would be left no way to access that VM.  The level of “privacy” would be nearly identical in either case.  The performance might be slightly better but it’s far more likely the problem is the CPU itself.  Mobile processors make horrible ESXi hosts

Comment: Okay, got the Type 1 terminology, but right now I'm using Type 2, and it's extremely slow, after having given 4GB RAM(half of my 8GB Config) and 90GB SSD, and I've enabled 3D Acc.. too